# How to implement the signin process with a Ledger device into a local app?

Tags: digital-signature

I developed some applications for Linux and Windows. Some of them need a classic login/password to sign-in and start the app. I wish to add or implement the sign-in process of a Ledger device into a application, in order to replace the login/password with sign-in from the Ledger device (web3 wallet). Do you have some documentations or first steps to me?